# SOAPUI Groovy script to read CSV and assign to properties

Tags: csv, properties, soapui

CSV structure and contents:

```
ClientRef,Status,Type,Service
107547,NEW,Inspection,Pest
107321,ALL,WorkOrder,Pest
107443,UPDATED,Collection,Bin
107291,ALL,Delivery,Bin
107411,ALL,Abandoned,Env
107189,NEW,Food,Env
107219,NEW,Protection,Env
```

I've set up SOAPUI Properties for `ClientRef`, `Status`, `Type` and `Service`, but need to populate the content from the CSV file into the properties above to submit a SOAP Request. How can I do that?

Comment: ok, we see the CSV.  if you expect help supply your code.

Comment: Are you using `ReadyAPI`?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. I used [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read the data into a `List` of beans, then iterated over the list and called a test case which would contain your SOAP request.

```
    import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName
    import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder

    public class RequestBean {

        @CsvBindByName(column = "ClientRef", required = true)
        private String clientRef;

        @CsvBindByName(column = "Status", required = true)
        private String status;

        @CsvBindByName(column = "Type", required = true)
        private String type;

        @CsvBindByName(column = "Service", required = true)
        private String service;

        public String getClientRef() {
            return clientRef;
        }

        public void setClientRef(String clientRef) {
            this.clientRef = clientRef;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getService() {
            return service;
        }

        public void setService(String service) {
            this.service = service;
        }
    }


    // Read the CSV values into a bean
    List<RequestBean> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader("/path-to/RequestDataFile.csv"))
        .withType(RequestBean.class)
        .build()
        .parse()

    // Iterate through the bean, setting project-level properties and execute a test case.
    beans.each {

        testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "ClientRef", it.clientRef )
        testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "Status", it.status )
        testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "Type", it.type )
        testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "Service", it.service )

        // Execute the test case
        //def testCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite").getTestCaseByName("TestCase")
        //def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap ()
        //testCase.run(properties, false)
    }
```

You'll need to see the [soapUI documentation for more about setting properties](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html) through Groovy and resolving external JARs like OpenCSV.

Comment: Cheers Craig, definitely a great help - Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded OPENCSV 3.9 Jar file and placed this in bin\ext but must be missing something as I'm getting multiple errors - TestCase failed [org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 9: unexpected token: beans @ line 9, column 1.
   beans.each {
   ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: beans @ line 9, column 1.
 at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)

Comment: You'll need version 4.1 for the CSV-to-bean feature.  It's available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/

Comment: Downloaded 4.1 (thanks) restarted but still the same errors - do I need to declare OPENCSV anywhere else in SOAPUI - running v5.3.0

Comment: Looks to be the "beans.each" statements - // Iterate through the bean, setting project-level 
// properties and execute a test case.
beans.each {

Comment: Sorry - I missed )) ending line 4 for the beans issue - now getting the following from ".StringToObjectMap ()" 
  org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script10.groovy: 26: expecting '(', found '.' @ line 26, column 13.

Comment: OpenCSV come with it's own dependencies (Apache Commons BeanUtils 1.9.3 and Commons Lang3 3.7), which you'll need to drop into the ext directory as well. BeanUtils 1.9.3 is a later version than soapUI 5.4 ships with, so you'll need to drop it into soapUI's lib directory and remove the exisiting version. And, of course, and changes to these directories requires a restart to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your patients, carried out your recommendations but SOAPUI will no longer load.  I've run the soapui.bat and extracted these comments from the log -  LINE2 log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.  LINE52 22:07:42,817 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [The plugin 'C:\Users\ssadmin\.soapuios\plugins\soapui-readyapi-export-results-plugin-1.3.jar' has unsigned class files.], see error log for details. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils